# Opening a Form from Another Form C#

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio

I have forms 'Form1','Form2' and a mdi. Mdi contains a splitcontainer. In split container there is two panels first one for menu and the other for displaying forms when we click on the menu. My issue is I want to call Form2 from Form1 when I click on an icon in the Form1. I wrote the bellow code in Form1 's icon click. But the Form2 is not showing. I wrote another alternative code like Form2.show() in this case Form2 is displaying but not fit in the panel2 of the Mdi. It is displaying like a popup. 
This is the code that I wrote in the Form1 icon click.

```
    private void icon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
        Form2 obj2 = new Form2 ();
        obj2 .Show();
        obj2 .Location = new Point(0, 0);
        obj2 .TopLevel = false;
        Mdi Objmdi = new Mdi();            
        Objmdi.splitContainerControl1.Panel2.Controls.Add(obj2);                      Objmdi.splitContainerControl1.Panel2.Controls["Form2"].BringToFront();
    }
```

Comment: What type is Form2? Is it a Window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an object reference to form 2 in the button_click event and call the 'show' function.

```
Form1 main = new Form1();
        main.Hide();
        Form2 second = new Form2();
        second.Show();
        second.Width = this.Width;
        second.Height = this.Height;
        second.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
        second.Location = new Point(this.Location.X, this.Location.Y);
        this.Visible = false;
```

Comment: I already tried this code. The form2 is displayed but its location is somewhere else not fit in the panel2 of the Mdi

Comment: I have updated the answer. Do check if it helps :)  @ancy

Comment: I updated my code with this but still the problem exsist. Form2 is showing but not fit in the splitcontainer. It shows out of the splitcontainer panel. I dont want to open the Form2 like new window.

Comment: "this" keywork refers to the current form.
Replace "this" with splitContainerControl1.Panel2

Comment: it works but the form opens like a new window. It showing in the tast bar.

Comment: Its working... i managed it to showintaskbar=false.@hustlecoder

Answer (score 0):

When a form is closed, all resources created within the object are closed and the form is disposed.

So when you call `this.Close();` code after this is not executed.

Change it to `this.Hide();`.

OR

Change it to `this.Hide();` and pass Form1's reference to Form2, which should close it.

Also,
You are creating a new MDI in the below line:

> Mdi Objmdi = new Mdi();
>           Objmdi.splitContainerControl1.Panel2.Controls.Add(obj2);                     Objhome.splitContainerControl1.Panel2.Controls["Form2"].BringToFront();

Instead of creating a new MDI use existing MDI's reference to do this operation.

Thirdly, `Controls["Form2"]` try changing to Controls["obj2"]

Comment: I changed this.Close() into this.Hide(). But still the problem existing, that means Form2 is not showing.

Comment: Added more details.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your Form2 to be displayed in some panel instead of a new window then you should create a UserControl instead of a Form and then you should be able to call `Objmdi.splitContainerControl1.Panel2.Controls.Add(myNewUserControl);`